# Delete item from RecyclerView - will not be changed

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm loading data from Firestore and displaying it in a StaggeredGridLayout. If I try to delete an item from this list, the item is removed from Firestore but the RV is not renewed.
The clicked position is correct.
I wonder why

MainActivity.tk:

```
  db.collection("shots")
        .addSnapshotListener { snapshots, e ->
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "listen:error", e)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }

            for (dc in snapshots!!.documentChanges) {
                when (dc.type) {

                    DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED -> {

                       //Nothing happens in RV
                        shotAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(shotClickedPos)
                        shotAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(shotClickedPos, dataSetShots.size)

                    }

                    else -> {}
                }
            }
        }

   override fun onShotClicked(shot: Shot, position: Int) {

    shotClickedPos = position
    val intent = Intent(applicationContext,CreateNewShot::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("updateOrCreate",true)
    intent.putExtra("shot",shot)
    intent.putExtra("position",position)

    startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE_UPDATE)

   }
```

CreateNewShot.tk:

```
 deleteShot.setOnClickListener {

        val id = shot.uuid
        db.collection("shots").document(id)
            .delete()
            .addOnSuccessListener {

                val intent = Intent()
                setResult(RESULT_OK,intent)
                finish()

            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e) }
    }
```

Comment: Try to surround `shotAdapter.notifyItemRemoved` with `activity.runOnUiThread` block

Comment: No, changes nothing

Answer (score 0):

While this answer is technically the 'best' solution, try either adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() or to set the recyclerView's adapter to a new instance of the adapter with the updated data set.